# Access denied mysqli when pushed to production server

Tags: php, mysqli

I have looked at a load of related answers to this question but.. the solutions are still not working for me!! My code works fine within the localhost test environment but not in production.

here is my code :

```
<h1> Security clearances Due to Expire</h1>
<?php
$db['user'] = 'prometheus';
$db['password'] = '';
$db['host'] = '*****.manchester.mpl.local';

$ingeniumMySQL = new mysqli($db['host'], $db['user'], $db['password'], "ingenium");
if ($ingeniumMySQL->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $ingeniumMySQL->connect_error;
}

$sqlone="SELECT person_security_levels.clearance_expires_date,
   person.forename,
   person.surname
FROM person_security_levels, person

where person_security_levels.person_id= person.id and person_security_levels.clearance_expires_date between NOW() AND  DATE_ADD( NOW() ,
 INTERVAL +3 MONTH)
LIMIT 5000
";
$resultone= mysqli_query($ingeniumMySQL,$sqlone);
echo '<table id="magictable" style="float: left; margin: 0 30px 0 50px;">';
echo'<td colspan="3"><h3>Clearances Expiring within Three Months</h3></td>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th class="headcolumn">Forename</th>';
echo '<th class="headcolumn">Surname</th>';
echo '<th class="headcolumn">Date Expires</th>';
echo '</tr>';

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultone)) {

    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['forename'] . "</td><td>" . $row['surname'] . "</td><td>" . $row['clearance_expires_date'] . "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

$sqltwo="SELECT person_security_levels.clearance_expires_date,
   person.forename,
   person.surname
FROM person_security_levels, person

where person_security_levels.person_id= person.id and person_security_levels.clearance_expires_date between NOW() AND  DATE_ADD( NOW() ,
    INTERVAL +1 MONTH)
LIMIT 5000";

$resultwo= mysqli_query($ingeniumMySQL,$sqltwo);
echo '<table class="magictable" style="float: left; margin: 0 30px 0 50px;">';
echo'<td colspan="3"><h3>Clearances Expiring within One Month</h3></td>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th class="headcolumn">Forename</th>';
echo '<th class="headcolumn">Surname</th>';
echo '<th class="headcolumn"> Date Expires</th>';
echo '</tr>';

while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($resultwo)) {

    echo "<tr><td>" . $rows['forename'] . "</td><td>" . $rows['surname'] . "</td><td>" . $rows['clearance_expires_date'] . "</td></tr>";
}
    echo "</table>";


$sqlthree="SELECT person_security_levels.clearance_expires_date,
   person.forename,
   person.surname
FROM person_security_levels, person

where person_security_levels.person_id= person.id and person_security_levels.clearance_expires_date between NOW() AND  DATE_ADD( NOW() ,
    INTERVAL+2 WEEK)
LIMIT 5000";

$resulthree= mysqli_query($ingeniumMySQL,$sqlthree);
echo '<table class="magictable" style="float: left; margin: 0 30px 0 50px;">';
echo'<td colspan="3"><h3>Clearances Expiring within Two Weeks</h3></td>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th class="headcolumn">Forename</th>';
echo '<th class="headcolumn">Surname</th>';
echo '<th class="headcolumn"> Date Expires</th>';
echo '</tr>';

while ($roe = mysqli_fetch_array($resulthree)) {

    echo "<tr><td>" . $roe['forename'] . "</td><td>" . $roe['surname'] . "</td><td>" . $roe['clearance_expires_date'] . "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";


$sqlfour="SELECT person_security_levels.clearance_expires_date,
   person.forename,
   person.surname
FROM person_security_levels, person

where person_security_levels.person_id= person.id and person_security_levels.clearance_expires_date between NOW() AND  DATE_ADD( NOW() ,
    INTERVAL+7 DAY)
LIMIT 5000";

$resultfour= mysqli_query($ingeniumMySQL,$sqlfour);
echo '<table class="magictable" style="float: left; margin: 0 30px 0 50px;">';
echo'<td colspan="3"><h3>Clearances Expiring within Seven Days</h3></td>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th class="headcolumn">Forename</th>';
echo '<th class="headcolumn">Surname</th>';
echo '<th class="headcolumn">Date Expires</th>';
echo '</tr>';

while ($roes = mysqli_fetch_array($resultfour)) {

    echo "<tr><td>" . $roes['forename'] . "</td><td>" . $roes['surname'] . "</td><td>" . $roes['clearance_expires_date'] . "</td></tr>";
}
mysqli_close($ingeniumMySQL);

?>
```

I am querying a database to produce result sets in html tables.
Full privileges are granted to the user specified , 
Dummy Users have been created for testing on different accounts and I am using the latest mysqli.

Here is the error displayed in production (appreciate any suggestions):

> Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]: (28000/1045): Access
>   denied for user 'prometheus'@'****.manchester.mpl.local' (using
>   password: YES) in
>   /storage/www/z-ingenium/application/views/scripts/reports/clearance-expires.phtml
>   on line 7 Failed to connect to MySQL: Access denied for user
>   'prometheus'@'solutions.manchester.mpl.local' (using password: YES)

Comment: Looks like you haven't set a password in your production server. Try removing the password.

Comment: Have you verified the MySQL connection from the command line? (realise you may have removed the password from the source code before posting here.)

Comment: Is your database on another host? Is the database server's `bind address` configured to allow remote hosts? By default it is only set to allow from localhost.

Comment: Hi @Rvanlaak -This is something Im not sure how to check as The original developer has the credentials to access the web server I don't. Is there any other way I could check this information?

Answer (score 0):

The password `$db['password'] = '';` for the mysql user `prometheus@solutions.manchester.mpl.local` is wrong.
Is it right that there is a local address in production mode?

Comment: Hi @A.M.N.Bandra I have left out the password for posting on here in my code there is a password present

Comment: Thanks @William Turrell production server and localhost is within the same domain the address is correct

Comment: What does mean production? What is different?

Comment: One is a local test environment and production is the Live site.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies for the late response! .. I have now resolved this issue! by checking the application.ini file the credentials for the production database were housed there which were different to the ones I was using. After correcting  this information it now works perfectly :)